# Custom object particle system using libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, particle-system

I have some working experience with libgdx particle systems, in the *.p file we define the effect and also provide an image resource which acts as the basic particle.

My requirement is to use a constructed object as particle, say a "[Utah teapot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_teapot)" which i generate from mesh. How to use such kind of objects as particles?

Thanks in advance.